# "semi-bold" font in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, font-weight

Is there a way to adjust a font width between normal and "Faux Bold" in Adobe Photoshop? Or define how thick will be a font while "Faux Bold" is set?

Comment: HI István, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Be warned that *faux* bold is already considered a, pun intended, *faux pas* in typography, let alone *faux* semibold. If you have any questions about GD.SE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: By "Faux Bold" I mean to set the characters as bold in the Character preferences

Comment: I know what you mean, I just thought I'd warn you about the fact that it's a somewhat deprecated practice. For what it's worth, I don't think there's any out-of-the box functionality like this in Photoshop, but you might be able to find a plug-in that does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not *really*. It's best to actually purchase a font with the weights you wish to use.

That being posted, you *could* just apply a **stroke layer style** to a text layer I suppose. Of course, this may slightly round the corners of some characters.

Comment: You suppose right – but a quick experiment gives me a stroke that's even *bolder* than Photoshop's own Faux.

Comment: That would depend upon the *size* of the type @Jongware :) Since 1pt is the smallest possible stroke... it would be rather heavy on smaller type sizes.

Comment: It does depend on the size, but I noticed the difference even on 128 pt text. PS's faux is actually more subtle than one would think; it even increases the spacing a bit. (Can't believe I am saying that :P)

Comment: You know that "faux" is only faux if a font does *not* contain a bold variant, right? If there's a bold variant for a family, that variant is used and it's not faux at all.

Comment: Yes I know. I actually had to browse quite a bit to find a font in my system for which I do *not* have a real bold. I ended up with Papyrus.

Comment: If someone was REALLY determined to muck around with a font, they could a) make their type really big, b) add a layer stroke, c) flatten the layer, d) shrink it down... not good practice though...

Comment: I figured you probably knew that Jongware :)